# SQL Server 2008 Query Editor changes the query logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I hand coded a simple SQL in SQL Server 2008 as below;

`SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE
A='1' AND (B='1' OR C='1');`

Being lazy I opened this query in the Query Editor to validate the syntax and pressed OK on the dialog without making any changes.

I noticed that the Query Editor had changed my query to:

`SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE A='1' AND (B='1') OR (C='1');`

clearly this changes the logic of the SQL and returns different results depending on which one you execute.

I routinely use the Query Editor to validate my syntax on complex queries.  So a little worried that the a subtle change like this would go unotice, but would change the outcome.

Is this a feature of the designer?  Is there something I can do to change this behavior?

**EDIT: Thanks for pointing out that the changes made by the editor is not quite the same as above, but still the query is modified although the results are the same.**

Thanks

Comment: Man, that is a scary thought if its changing queries!

Comment: Did a check, and it resolved correctly for me to: SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE (A='1' AND B='1') OR (A='1' AND C='1');. Tested with version 2008, so it might depend on something else.

Comment: "pressed OK on the dialog "
I don't get any "OK" when I syntax check.

Comment: Wait, are you SQL Management Studio?

Comment: I strongly recommend not using the query designer or query editor in Management Studio - they are full of bugs and lack some basic T-SQL functionality. A similar bug has been open for almost 6 years: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124819/query-designer-alters-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to replicate this in the Query Designer and had a slightly different result. I typed the same as you:

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE A='1' AND (B='1' OR C='1');
```

And got this:

```
SELECT     *
FROM         Tab1
WHERE     (A = '1') AND (B = '1') OR
                      (A = '1') AND (C = '1')
```

I have to say that the result is the same, but we can all see a **dangerous** road here. Also, I did not like the `(A = '1')` replication. Heck, I want the code how I coded it!

A word to the wise: I **never** format my queries in SQL Server Management Studio. Have you seen what it does to your view's code? I hate it. I just code somewhere else and paste in SMS when done.

Comment: Yes, both Adrian and MicSim are correct. I think I jumped the guns a little with panic, BECAUSE of the new duplicated condition with my brackets messed around as you pointed out. Will be wary of it though.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE A='1' AND (B='1' OR C='1')
```

resolves for me to:

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE (A='1') AND (B='1') OR (A='1') AND (C='1')
```

This is *surprisingly correct*, as in SQL Server TSQL the `AND` operator has precedence over `OR`. That means the above is the same like the following, because the `AND`-operator gets evaluated before the `OR`-operator:

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE ((A='1') AND (B='1')) OR ((A='1') AND (C='1'))
```

And this is the same like the initial statement being used in the question.

See [Operator Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx?ppud=4) for details.